# metamask log in

Tags: metamask

During my first use of Meta, I was unable to save my private key and 12 words, and after reinstalling the metamask in Chrome, I was unable to log in.
Only the private json file and password are known.If I can't log in, how can I find my private key in my json file or data stored on my computer? 
Please help me

Answer (score 1):

If your account was created in MetaMask, then 12 word seed phrase was the only way to restore it. If you have a hard drive backup, that could help.

If your account was imported into MetaMask using a JSON keystore, you can re-import it into any instance of MetaMask once you set it up again (configure a new password, etc).

Make sure to backup your seed phrase next time!